# How do I look up my teamID for a call to the ESPN API?

Tags: api

I'm a Louisiana-based iOS noob looking to learn by building a simple New Orleans Saints news feed app. I want to pull data from the free ESPN API. It seems like the syntax for the API call is:

```
/sports/:sportName/:leagueAbbrev/teams/:teamId/news
```

How do I look up the parameters for this call? How do I find out the :teamID for the Saints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did an API call to api.espn.com/v1/sports/football/nfl/teams and scrolled thru the output until I found the saints. Then I found the ID for the saints = 18. So the call is api.espn.com/v1/sports/football/nfl/teams/18/news

Comment: That's the structure for getting IDs for teams across all leagues.   So for MLB it's sports/baseball/mlb/teams.